# Is it possible to add an element to the bottom tool bar of a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiprogressview

I want to add a progressview and an activity indicator view to the tool bar that come at the bottom of the navigation controller. But when I drag and drop it, it becomes applicable to the whole window?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could understand your question, your problem is when adding the activity indicator on the toolbar. Because to add the UIProgressView is not a problem.

To do that, you have to first add a UIView on your toolbar, and then insert the activity indicator inside this view.

Let me know if it works, for you!

Cheers,
VFN